# nginx "connect() failed (104: Connection reset by peer)"

Tags: nginx

I met So many "connect() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while connecting to upstream" in error.log; Anybody has ideas?

Comment: Your upstream servers are overloaded.

Comment: That means my wsgi application can't bear my ab test?

Comment: 104 error is not always overload issue. This is one of complex nginx/backend error when you need dig into logs... even into segfaults and core dumps. Got it several times with PHP 5.4 and APC extension, try to turn off it if you have PHP 5.4 (I has migrate to 5.5 and Zend Optimizer)

Comment: Curious why you're asking this as this is exactly the only thing ab testing is good for: checking if your backend threads are scaled up high enough to handle requests in the idealist of circumstances. And yes, look in you gunicorn or uwsgi logs to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and all those connection became unavailable. After I changed to use haproxy as reverse proxy, the problem had been solved.